# Text is overflowing in code tag instead of scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, rainbow-js

Use of `rainbow.js` to highlight the code causing code in `<code>` tag to overflow (x). CSS overflow property doesn't seem to work (even with `!important`)

Code containing `<code>` tag

```
<pre>
    <code>
            Any code to be highligted
    </code>
</pre>
```

CSS :

```
code {
    overflow: auto; /* Not working (scroll also not working) */
    width: 100%;
}
```

Replacement of `<code>` tag with `<div>` eliminates the overflow problem but highlighting doesn't work (this plugin requires code to be put in `<code>` tag)

How can I resolve this overflow issue to provide scroll? Or do I need to use any other code highlighting library?

• With `code` tag (highlight yes, scroll no) **Overflow** [image: With code tag (highlight yes, scroll no )]
• With `div` tag (highlight no, scroll yes) [image: With div tag (highlight no, scroll yes)]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Oram I've provided CSS for code tag and code containing `code` tag overflowing (top image). And scrollable un-highlighted `div` tag (bottom image)   [link to webpage https://qnaboard.ml/index.php?f=audio-video.html ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `overflow` property in the `code` element, you should use it in the `pre` element.

`pre`, by default, has `white-space: pre` declaration, which renders new lines only if the HTML inside has a `<br>` tag or a newline character, and that's why the text won't break if reaches the limit of the parent element. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space for more details.

So, using `overflow: auto` in the `pre` element should solve it :)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue using `highlightjs` and resolved it using:

```
code {
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  overflow: auto; /* Or scroll */
}
```

**Explanation**

To the best of my knowledge, in order for child elements to cause overflow within a parent container, in this case, the parent container should have a fixed value for `width` or `min-width`. And `max-width: 100%` did not work for me.

So I gave a static value of `width: 0px` to cause overflowing to kick-in and `min-width: 100%`. The parent element obeys the `min-width` because `min-width` has higher precedence over `width`.

Answer (score 1):

```css
code {
  white-space: pre-line;
 }
```

I got the same overflow issue.
This works well for me.